# ASP.NET-WEBFORMS, wait for a job until he done, when parameter changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, webforms

I scaling the app from single user to multiple users.
each user have a group of IP cameras, when he click on a button the APP connecting to his cameras
and snapping images. the SDK has a delegate for image callback and you have to wait for all the images and show it Immediately in gallery.
for one user i was used `AutoResetEvent wait= new AutoResetEvent(false);`.
but now we have more than one user and in parallel mode the first user's job done reset the event
and the second user stuck.

Any ideas how I can to separate the waiting ????

Button Event

```
protected void btn_capture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
 //db job for each user
.
.
AutoResetEvent wait4all = new AutoResetEvent(false);

 Cams cams = new Cams( cameraList, businessPath, cropsList);
  cams.SetAllCallBack();

  cams.CaptureAll(ref wait4all, ref imgUrl, ref plate, ref plateDetails);

//wait here when callback triggered as a number of snapping    
wait4all.WaitOne();

}
```

Init func

```
 public void SetAllCallBack()
        {
            //set disconnect callback.
            disConnect = new fDisConnectCallBack(DisConnect);

            try
            {
                bool res = NETClient.Init(disConnect, IntPtr.Zero, null); //init NetClient.
                if (res == false)
                {
                    // LogsWriter.LogWriter("exception", new string[] { "", String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()), " NETClient init failed!" });
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // LogsWriter.LogWriter("exception", new string[] { "", String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()), "Reconnect callback function - " + ((NETClientExcetion)ex).Message.ToString() });

            }



            m_RealDataCallBack = new fRealDataCallBackEx(RealDataCallBack); //instance realdata callback.
            m_RealPlayDisConnectCallBack = new fRealPlayDisConnectCallBack(RealPlayDisConnectCallBack); //instance realplay disconnect callback.
            m_ReConnectCallBack = new fHaveReConnectCallBack(ReConnectCallBack); //instance reconnect callback.
            m_SnapRevCallBack = new fSnapRevCallBack(SnapRevCallBack); // instance capture callback.
            NETClient.SetAutoReconnect(m_ReConnectCallBack, IntPtr.Zero); //set reconnect callback.
        }
```

Cam capture function

```
 [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.Synchronized)]
        // Capture all cameras except back 
        public void CaptureAll(string user, AutoResetEvent wait4allv, SortedDictionary<string, string> imgUrl, PlateDetails plateDetails)
        {
            log.Info("step3 all-" + user);

            this.wait4all = wait4all;// pass the event object to continue work
            this.imgesUrls = imgUrl;
            plateDetails = this.plateDetails;

            try
            {
                Device dev = null;

                foreach (var item in m_DeviceList1)
                {
                    // dev = item.Value;

                    if (dev == null)
                    {
                        // return; //if the stuck is empty
                    }
                    if (m_IsSetCaptureCallBack == false)
                    {
                        log.Info("call back");
                        NETClient.SetSnapRevCallBack(m_SnapRevCallBack, IntPtr.Zero);
                        m_IsSetCaptureCallBack = true;
                    }

                    NET_SNAP_PARAMS snap = new NET_SNAP_PARAMS();
                    snap.Channel = (uint)item.ChannelNum;
                    snap.Quality = 6;
                    snap.ImageSize = 2;
                    snap.mode = 0;
                    snap.InterSnap = 0;
                    snap.CmdSerial = m_SnapSerialNum;
                    bool ret = NETClient.SnapPictureEx(item.LoginID, snap, IntPtr.Zero); //call capture function.
                    log.Info("snap All - " + user + " " + ret);
                    if (ret)
                    {
                        m_SnapSerialNum++;
                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex is NETClientExcetion)
                {
                    // LogsWriter.LogWriter("exception", new string[] { "", String.Format("{0:d/M/yyyy HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now.ToUniversalTime()), "Capture all function - " + ((NETClientExcetion)ex).Message.ToString() });
                }
            }
        }
```

Callback func

```
private void SnapRevCallBack(IntPtr lLoginID, IntPtr pBuf, uint RevLen, uint encodeType, uint CmdSerial, IntPtr dwUser)
{
//save image
.
.
countSnap++;

//check if all images saved
  if (countSnap == countInit)
  {
     log.Info("if count " + businessId + "countSnap " + countSnap + " countInit");

            wait4all.Set();
   }



}
```

Comment: probably you must re-design your program in a different way but you show no code to get more ideas.

Comment: @Aristos I added the code, thanks

Comment: for start try to move the content of `btn_capture_Click` inside a handler (with out session opens) and send your results from the handler using probably and some javascript code. With the code on `btn_capture_Click` you block all your users because of the session lock

Comment: other way is to remove the thread from `btn_capture_Click` just hit it to make what is make there. No need for thread there. We place thread there in a desktop program to not hold the rest of the program from continue render - but in website you do not need to have any thread there. Just call it to make what have to make with out any thread.